# DbFunctions TruncateTime return value

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My application is MVC 5, EF 6.1 and SQL Server.
I am using

```
 public JsonResult GetUserDates()
        {
            var id= "1231231234";
            var data = db.Test.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(c =>
            new
            {
                Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Date)}).Distinct().ToList();
   return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

it returns the date correct however in the dropdownlist it looks like this:

```
2016-1-12 00:00:00:00000000
```

How can I get rid of extra zeros.  The Data Type in the table is date.

Comment: `How can I get rid of extra zeros`  how many extra zeros do you have in your example? What about for `2016-1-1**0** 00:00:00:00000000`?

Comment: are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes I am using EF 6.1, the extra zeros as shown in my question, they look like time!

Comment: So you want only the date part of Datetime class? Question changes......

Comment: yes, only the date part. Thank you

Comment: are you using SQL Server ? Why do you need to remove the extra zero ?

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL server and want to remove the extra zero. The data type in sql is date.  Thank you

Comment: TO help efficiently you must put on your question the scenario were you want to do that ?

Comment: You could use something like this to show only the date as a string  DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.date).Value.ToShortDateString() .
Other ways of formatting the date can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I got this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: Put in the question the query you are writing at least if you can't your controller ation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeNotFound's solution is acceptable, but alternatively, you can build the string in .NET instead of in SQL, like this:

```
public JsonResult GetUserDates()
{
    var id= "1231231234";
    var data = db.Test.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(c => c.Date).Distinct()
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(x => new { 
                     Date = x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                 });

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Anything following `.AsEnumerable()` will execute after query results are returned from the SQL Server to .NET.  This is slightly better, as the data will be sent in its native binary format in the underlying TDS protocol, rather than a string.

The final `ToList` you had is not necessary.

Note that if your field is nullable, and thus you declared your object as `DateTime?`, that you'll make a minor adjustment:

Using C# 6 `?.` notation:

```
Date = x?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Or if you're still on C# 5, then:

```
Date = x == null ? null : x.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Also, I kept the results in the same structure you presented, but you might find it's easier to return an array of date strings instead of an array of objects containing a "Date" field.  Something to think about.

I'll also say that this is only a good solution because of two important details you provided:

1. The data field in SQL is a `date` type.  If it is actually a `datetime`, `datetime2`, `smalldatetime` or `datetimeoffset`, then you would want to do a *range query* instead of the `Distinct`.
2. The results are going into a `JsonResult`, which would normally serialize a `DateTime` using the ugly `"/Date(<ts>)/"` format, where `<ts>` is a unix-time-like number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.  However, since you are working with a date, and not a date-time, then using this format could cause the browser to interpret the date as UTC midnight, and for some time zones could shift to the other side of midnight, and thus result in a different date.  Thus, sending a string in ISO-8601 format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) is a much better approach.

Comment: Thank you Matt, very helpful.  However I got an error: 
CS1501 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments, so I used
Date = x.Value.ToShortDateString()
I worked great.

Comment: Hmmm.. It's [right here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx).   You don't want `ToShortDateString`, because that will be *culture specific*, such as today being `"2/13/2016"` in the US or `"13/2/2016"` in other parts of the world.  For JSON, you really should stick with ISO8601, `"2016-02-13"`.

Comment: Is your `Test.Date` defined as `DateTime` or `DateTime?`

Comment: public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date

Comment: That's the same as `DateTime?`.  I updated the answer to account for that.

Comment: Nice insight Matt. I know, lame comment. All I got right now.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Why ToString() can be used inside LinQ (the code `Date = x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` ) ? It's that ToString is not supported in LinQ ?

Answer (score 3):

[TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx) won't do what you think it'd do. If you do not have the time part of `datetime` in your database truncating time does nothing. There was no time there to start with and there is no time there after truncation.

I think what you are missing here is the difference between data structure and it's human readable representation. `TruncateTime` function [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) type. This type is for storing both Time *and* Date. However you can use it for storing just date, or just time.

You do not provide any of your code, apart from this single line that achieves nothing, and you mention vaguely some time of "dropdownlist". Thus you making it quite difficult to answer your question. I will still try. For the future though, it helps to provide all the relevant code, (but none) of irrelevant, as no one likes scrolling through pages of code.

Most likely you are trying to use date from the database in some kind of control. And you are probably data binding the control to the result set. These are the key things to know to be able to answer your question but you are not supplying them.

Many controls would accept any object bound to them and will use (a child) implementation of [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the object to string for display in the control. By default [DateTime.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx) forms a string with both time *and* date. And that's probably what you are seeing.

Depending on your implementation, you might need to explicitly convert that to string using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) of ToString. You will be able to specify precise format for the output string using that, that is you can easily omit the time from the output.

Depending on your implementation you might also need to do the reverse conversion from `string` to `DateTime` after a user selects something from your control, and you want to communicate the result of your selection back to your code in `DateTime` format.

What to read about: String Formatting, Data Binding, Methods Overloading, Inheritance, Polymorphism.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for taking the time to explain.  You are correct I should have explained more.  I am using Knockout Kendo dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

You are using SQL server then you can use **SqlFunctions** static classes. If you don't want the extra zero you can use **SqlFunctions.DatePart**.

Replace the following code:

```
Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Date)
```

with this code:

```
Date = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", c.Date) + "-" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", c.Date) + "-" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", c.Date)
```